# VS 2010 setup shortcut file not shows Run as Administrator option

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have created a setup project for a windows application in VS2010 (C#). I have added project primary output in application folder and its shortcut to desktop folder. After installing the setup, the desktop contain shortcut exe file not shows "Run as Administrator" option on mouse right click.

I have seen  some post in stack overflow to set the tag in manifest file like this :

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
```

But I couldn't find any manifest file in my app. where its location? How to attcah this manifest to setup project?

Please help.

Comment: Changing manifest will force your app to run with elevated permissions. However, it probably wont fix your _Shortcut_ problem. See if this helps - http://wishmesh.com/2010/07/run-as-administrator-missing-for-shortcuts-created-by-visual-studio-setup-project/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a manifest file to your program.

Click `Project` -> `Add new item` -> add `Application Manifest File`

By default you will see there:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />`

Make sure to replace it with:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>`

Comment: I couldn't find View Windows Settings option .

Comment: Could you find `Application Manifest File` in `Add new item` ?

Comment: And? Setting the `requireAdministrator` helped ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with your installer. The `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>` should just force the application to ask for administrator rights before starting.

Check that the shortcut is targeting the exe correctly, for instance I had 2 shortcuts with different targets (right click on shortcut -> "Shortcut" tab -> Target):

Application 1 Shortcut -> Target "Application1" <- Run as administrator not working

Application 1 Shortcut -> Target "C:\Prorgram Files\App1\Application1.exe". <- Run as administrator working