# "Run as administrator" option doesn't shows up in the context menu in Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, manifest, mt

I'm using VS2012  WPF Application & Install-shield 2013 LE to generate the installer.

After the installation I noticed that "Run as administrator" option doesn't shows up in the context menu in Explorer of the `desktop icon`.

Some of the user couldn't run the application but they can run the application by getting into the installed dir and right click on the icon, Run as administrator.

I checked in this link :`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247046.aspx` then I added the option: "Embed manifest with default settings" and regenerated the installer. But it didn't make any change.

I'm making a test on Win 7 OS 32bit.

How can i enable the option "Run as administrator" when i right click on application icon in the context menu in Explorer?

Same problem like this question: [VS 2010 setup shortcut file not shows Run as Administrator option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849404/vs-2010-setup-shortcut-file-not-shows-run-as-administrator-option)

app.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
      Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows Vista, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
   <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

[image]

[image]

Edited:

I figured it out that the InstallShield 2013 LE(Limited Edition) is not allowing me to put the target directioy like this : `"C:\ProgramFiles\TestUtility.exe"`. If the target refer to exe, then the 'Run as Administrator' will be enabled automatically.

Original:

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

So, InstallShield LE is doesn't allow me to change that.

I have to find another way to generate the installer. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Did you try the solution in the linked question and if yes, did it fail for you?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: I tried adding a app.manifest file & build action to none. And generated a new installer still i don't see that option.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: Have the users tried holding shift when they right click on the executable?

Comment: @msm8bball: No. Just a classic installation. Problem is after installation when we right click on the icon there is no option to run as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why the 'Run as Administrator' is not enabled. When an installed icon is not referred to .exe it won't be available.

On top of this InstalShield 2013 LE version doesn't allow to change the "Target Directory" value.

Link: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?206542-Permissions-setting-to-edit-within-directory

It's important to refer the .exe; why? the user can run the application as an Administrator through Windows Explorer Context Menu.

I decided to go with WIX installer.

Please give me your FB.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171558/5818981).

Essentially, you need to disable "advertised links" in the msi. My answer is a composite answer from other sources that does this in the msi build schema thus making it a single fix for all your projects.

It's tested and works on Windows Pro 64bit.